# Laravel | MySQL | Запрос на создание записи

Tags: mysql, laravel

Есть запрос:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'login' => $data['login'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'privilege' => 1,
        'image' => '',
        'balance' => 0
    ]);
}
```

Ничего магического. Но при исполнении неожиданно вылетает:

**General error: 1364 Field 'login' doesn't have a default value**

```
"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'login' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (example@gmail.com, $2y$10$..., 2020-07-31 17:15:00, 2020-07-31 17:15:00))"
```

Ясное дело, мне в запросе не хватает 'login', но как его туда добавить? Я только начал учить фреймворк и мало понимаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в модели. Я не знал, что они отвечают за работу с бд. Зашел в User.php и изменил:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];
```

на

```
protected $fillable = [
    'login', 'email', 'password',
];
```

Теперь все работает правильно и ошибок не возникает.